# Is there a way to combine scss nesting and tailwindcss?

Tags: sass, tailwind-css

I'm new to tailwindcss, and i want to use both sassy css and tailwind for my new project. But I'm having trouble with the nesting specially when i used "@apply".

```
section {
  @apply .p-4;
  ul {
    li {
      @apply .ml-8 .text-red-600;
      li:last-child {
        @apply .text-gray-300;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the red color apply to all li but the last-child (gray color) is not working. I'm not sure if it's possible

Answer (score 2):

Right now we cant combine the SCSS and tailwind file. But we can achieve this by doing like this, give a class name to `ul` tag `mylist`

```
section {
  @apply .p-4;
}
.mylist li {
  @apply .ml-8 .text-red-600; 
}
.mylist li:last-child {
  @apply .text-gray-300;
}
```

Comment: You can use nesting through a plugin https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting

Answer (score 2):

You *can use Sass and Tailwind together*, though there are a few things to watch out for [as detailed in the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#using-sass-less-or-stylus).

Though, as also noted in the docs [it is recommended that you use PostCSS exclusively](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors/#using-postcss-as-your-preprocessor) as your pre-processor. You can use nesting, variables and much, much more with PostCSS, there's really nothing that you can do with Sass that you cannot do with PostCSS.

I switched my build process from using Sass to PostCSS exclusively, more than 3 years ago, and I've  not found anything missing. Indeed I can do so much more, I've never looked back.

Answer (score 1):

Selector you're trying to build here will be compiled to something like:

```
section ul li li:last-child {...}
```

I think what you're trying to achieve here is this:

```
section {
  @apply .p-4;
  ul {
    li {
      @apply .ml-8 .text-red-600;
    }
    li:last-child {
      @apply .text-gray-300;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work and has the wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Sure they can!

Nothing's wrong with them, there are couple of very small drawbacks but nothing special.

If your case, you have a tiny mistake in your code

```
section {
  @apply p-4;
  ul {
    li {
      @apply ml-8 text-red-600;

      &:last-child {
        @apply text-gray-300;
      }
    }
  }
}
```